# Polymorphic keys to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, polymorphism

I have a hierarchy of classes:

```
public class Key
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public Key(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;
        Key other = (Key)obj;
        return Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetType().GetHashCode() ^ _name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GetType() + "(" + Name + ")";
    }
}
```

Different keys:

```
public class CarKey : Key
{
    public CarKey(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }
}

public class VanKey : CarKey
{
    public VanKey(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }
}

public class CoupeKey : CarKey
{
    public CoupeKey(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }
}
```

and I have a dictionary `IDictionary<Key, Data>`. I would like to implement a method to find the most relevant data in the dictionary:

```
IDictionary<Key, Data> dict;
public Data MostRelevantData(Key key)
{
  if(dict.Contains(key)) return dict[key];
  //try base class of key (with the same name) recursively
  throw new KeyNotFound();
}
```

Is it possible to implement `MostRelevantData` without reflection? Feel free to redesign the `Key` classes if it makes it any easier.

EDIT: Example:

```
dict[new Key("A")] = "Data A";
dict[new CarKey("B")] = "Data B";
dict[new CoupeKey("B")] = "Data B1";
dict[new CoupeKey("C")] = "Data C";

MostRelevantData(new CoupeKey("B"));//returns "Data B1"
MostRelevantData(new CoupeKey("A"));//returns "Data A"
MostRelevantData(new CoupeKey("C"));//returns "Data C"

MostRelevantData(new CarKey("C"));//throws
MostRelevantData(new CarKey("B"));//returns "Data B"

MostRelevantData(new VanKey("C"));//throws
MostRelevantData(new VanKey("B"));//returns "Data B"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get a value based on its `Type`? Can you give an example, how you wish to use this code?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sounds like if an instance `CoupeKey` with `Name` "ASDF" wasn't found, that Grzenio would like it to see if there are any _other_ `CarKey` objects with the `Name` "ASDF" (that is, it could return a `VanKey` that happens to have the same "ASDF" `Name`). (Not sure how you would determine if a `VanKey` is more relevant than say, a `SedanKey` though if both had a matching `Name`)

Comment: @Grzenio: I would suggest having two dictionary lookup tables. One that's `Dictionary<Key, Data> dict` and another that's `Dictionary<string, List<Key>> NameLookup`. Whenever you add a `Key`, you would store an entry in the `NameLookup`. As Keys are added with matching names, they'll populate their respective `List<Key>` listings. When you do your lookup, if the `Key` doesn't exist in `dict`, then you can do a second check in `NameLookup`; if there's additional matching `Keys` there, you can then pull out their corresponding `Data` out of `dict`.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, added examples

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, this sounds reasonable. I am still not sure how to find the most relevant item in the list though...

Comment: @Grzenio: I added a sample implementation that passes your required tests. EDIT: out of simplicity, I suggest you use [Lee's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22562072/1269654) anyway is possible.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, I haven't really read your answer properly, but I think it will start breaking if you add `dict.Add(new Key("B"), new Data{ Name = "Data 0"});`, because then for `new VanKey("B")` you have to keys that are assignable...

Comment: @Grzenio: my edited (but I deleted) answer still worked for it. However, it didn't consider how deep the hierarchy was. That is, for `VanKey`, it should favour a matching `CarKey` before `Key`; so depending on the order entered, it would return different (but compatible) values. This would be relatively simple to update in the relevancy check, but regardless, I think Lee's solution is still simpler.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, I probably wasn't clear, but there is always at most one best value, that is the one with a key closest in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a method to `Key` to get a base key instance:

```
public class Key
{
    public virtual Key GetBaseKey()
    { return null; }
}

public class CarKey : Key
{
    public override Key GetBaseKey()
    { return new Key(this.Name); }
}
```

then your search can be written as:

```
public Data MostRelevantData(Key key)
{
  while(key != null)
  {
    if(dict.Contains(key)) return dict[key];
    key = key.GetBaseKey();
  }
  throw new KeyNotFound();
}
```

The downside is you'll have to effectively duplicate the key hierarchy in each subclass.

Comment: You could use reflection to implement `GetBaseKey` as a non-virtual method in `Key`

Comment: @Servy - Yes you could, the OP seems to want to avoid reflection.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to implement `MostRelevantData` without reflection. Here's an extension method:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensionMethods
{
    public static T MostRelevantData<T>(this IDictionary<Key, T> dict, Key key)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return dict[key];
        }
        Key relevantKey = dict.Keys.FirstOrDefault(
            loop => key.IsRelevant(loop));
        if (relevantKey != null)
        {
            return dict[relevantKey];
        }
        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Obviously, though, you'll need to implement `Key.IsRelevant` for this to work. Fortunately, that's pretty straightforward as well, courtesy of the [Type.IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
public class Key
{
    public bool IsRelevant(Key other)
    {
        return (this.GetType().IsSubclassOf(other.GetType()))
            && (this.Name == other.Name);
    }
}
```

With the above implementation, the following Visual Studio unit tests all pass:

```
public class PolymorphicKeysTests
{
    public PolymorphicKeysTests()
    {
    }

    private Dictionary<Key, string> dict;
    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<Key, string>();
        dict[new Key("A")] = "Data A";
        dict[new CarKey("B")] = "Data B";
        dict[new CoupeKey("B")] = "Data B1";
        dict[new CoupeKey("C")] = "Data C";
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CoupeKeyB()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Data B1", dict.MostRelevantData(new CoupeKey("B")));
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void CoupeKeyA()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Data A", dict.MostRelevantData(new CoupeKey("A")));
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void CoupeKeyC()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Data C", dict.MostRelevantData(new CoupeKey("C")));
    }
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(KeyNotFoundException))]
    public void CarKeyC()
    {
        dict.MostRelevantData(new CarKey("C"));
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void CarKeyB()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Data B", dict.MostRelevantData(new CarKey("B")));
    }
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(KeyNotFoundException))]
    public void VanKeyC()
    {
        dict.MostRelevantData(new VanKey("C"));
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void VanKeyB()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Data B", dict.MostRelevantData(new VanKey("B")));
    }
}
```